# Unable to detect when a USB is plugged/unplugged with inotify

Tags: usb, android, inotify

I'm trying to detect when a USB device (Android Device) is plugged into my computer.

I know when I plug a device in, this file is changed `/sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices` and if I do a grep for the UDID of the plugged-in device it will give me the `S:  SerialNumber=` line. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24582905/6890234)

Now, in theory, I can use inotifywait to check for modifications on the `devices` file and know that some device is plugged in or plugged out. [Source](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait)

But when I do the inotifywait on it, it is not able to detect that the file is modified. And I know for sure that the file is modified, I even checked it's md5sum before and after plugging in a device, they were different.

This was the command I was using

```
inotifywait -m /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices
```

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Yes It does thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you also think that the proposed duplicate solves your problem, you may want to consider agreeing with that close vote. As a side note however, would a `udev` rule also be an option to solve your problem?